# Unspecified error Code 80004005 in using Navigate2

Tags: vbscript

Okay I've update the whole thread guys. I have 4 urls on my text file, the first 2 or 3 opens but upon opening the 4th, I'm getting an error on my code like this:

```
Windows Script Host
Script: [file path]
Line: 23
Char: 3
Error: Unspecified error
Code: 80004005
Source: (null)
```

This is as far as I have:

```
Option Explicit

' Constants
Const ForReading = 1
Const navOpenInNewTab = 2048

Dim oIE, filename, fso, f

Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True

filename = "C:\StartIt\urls.txt"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(filename, ForReading)

Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
    If f.Line = 1 Then
        oIE.Navigate2 removeDelimiter(f.ReadLine)
    Else
        oIE.Navigate2 removeDelimiter(f.ReadLine), navOpenInNewTab ' This is line 23
    End if
Loop
Set oIE = Nothing
f.Close

WScript.Quit

' Methods
Function removeDelimiter(s)
  If Right(s, 1) = "," Then
    removeDelimiter = Left(s, Len(s) - 1)
  Else
    removeDelimiter = s
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: What doesn't work as expected? With the `Navigate2` calls commented you should have an infinite loop (because you never read the file to the end), but other than that it should work AFAICS.

Comment: Okay I have added the updated code. Now the error says `"Unspecified error: Code 80004005`

Comment: What is the content of that line?